# Sending Email from Outlook365 with Yagmail in Python (Allowing SMTP access)

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, outlook, yagmail

I can send emails via a Gmail account using the `Yagmail` module in Python but I am getting a `SMTPAuthenticationError` when I try to do it with an Outlook email address.

Gmail required me to allow "less secure apps" to access my account but I can't find any such option for Outlook365.

This is my code for Gmail with Yagmail:

```
import keyring
keyring.set_password('yagmail', 'user@gmail.com', 'mypassword')

import yagmail
FROM = "user@gmail.com"
TO = "other@email.com"
SUBJECT = "test email"
TEXT = "details go here"

yagmail.SMTP(FROM).send(TO, SUBJECT, TEXT)
```

Comment: I have unfortunately no idea about outlook on that matter....

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work using the following:

```
import yagmail
FROM = 'user@gmail.com'
TO = 'other@email.com'
SUBJECT = 'test email'
TEXT = 'details go here'

yag = yagmail.SMTP('myO365email.com', 'myO365pw', host='smtp.office365.com', port=587, smtp_starttls=True, smtp_ssl=False)
yag.send(TO, SUBJECT, TEXT)
```

The trick was to configure the SMTP TLS/SSL options.

Comment: Thanks, also got stuck for a minute on the ssl, tsl config.

Comment: This no longer seems to work. I think this is because of the latest and the greatest Microsoft trick of two-factor authentication. Does anyone know a solution for that?

Comment: `FROM` is not used anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The answer of dnlbrky still works with 2FA. If you've activated 2FA you need to generate an app password, see here: [*Using app passwords with apps that don't support two-step verification*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944)

When generated, fill the second param here instead of your regular password:

```
yag = yagmail.SMTP('myO365email.com', 'mynewapppassword', host='smtp.office365.com', port=587, smtp_starttls=True, smtp_ssl=False)
```